# How to address multiple nested_resources in rails forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-routing

I've

```
resources :projects do
  resources :sounds, shallow: true
end

resources :sounds, only: [:show, :edit, :update; :destroy] do
  resources :comments, shallow: true
end
```

now I want to create a comment in the /sounds/sound_id/ path

```
# app/views/sounds/show
<%= form_with url: sound_comments_path(@sound.id) do |form| %> # I want to address comment#create 
  <%= form.label :text %>
  <%= form.text_field :text %>
  <%= form.submit "Create comment" %>
<% end %>
```

all I've tried so far didn't work. What would be the goto solution for this?

Here are the requested routes:

```
edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit                                                           
comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format) comments#show                                                                 
        PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format) comments#update                                                                  
        PUT    /comments/:id(.:format) comments#update                                                                  
        DELETE /comments/:id(.:format) comments#destroy                                                                 
sound_comments GET    /sounds/:sound_id/comments(.:format)comments#index                                                     
               POST  /sounds/:sound_id/comments(.:format)comments#create 
new_sound_comment GET/sounds/:sound_id/comments/new(.:format) comments#new                                                
                      GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)                                                             comments#edit
                      GET    /comments/:id(.:format)                                                                  comments#show
                      PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format)                                                                  comments#update
                      PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)                                                                  comments#update
                      DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)                                                                  comments#destroy
```

When I try to create a comment I get this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: comment):

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:72:in `comment_params'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

If I do form_with with model: [:sounds, Comment.new] I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ffe52183370>:0x007ffe587cb8a8>
Did you mean?  comment_path):
    1: <%= form_with(model: @comment, local: true) do |form| %>
    2:   <% if comment.errors.any? %>
    3:     <div id="error_explanation">
    4:       <h2><%= pluralize(comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>
```

Comment: could you post rake routes from console

Answer (score 0):

I think `sound_comments_path` should have include sound_id, like `sound_comments_path(sound_id)`. Make sure u generate right routes for your form.